# Limit function of $\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+x^2}$ as $\epsilon\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

What is the limit of the sequence of functions$\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+x^2}$ as $\epsilon\to 0$?

I think this just doesn't exist, since it goes to $\infty$ in $x=0$ and goes to $0$ everywhere else.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit the nail on the head there with your thoughts, except that the interpretation should be that the limit *does* exist, whenever $x\neq 0$, but does not exist, when $x=0$.

The limit will depend on which value of $x$ you are given.

Comment: But that means that 'The limit function' as a whole, (which is just defined pointwise) does not exist right? Now I know about the dirac delta (also mentioned in the other answer) but I don't think it really counts as a function on the real numbers. I've also heard it's more correctly referred to as a distribution instead of a function.

Comment: Yes, I agree with this. The limit does not exist as a function on all of $\mathbb{R}$. It only exists on $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. @user2520938

Answer (score 2):

For each $f$ 
$$
\int f(x)\times \frac {\epsilon }{x^2 + \epsilon ^ 2} dx
= \int f(\epsilon y) \times \frac { 1}{y^2 + 1} dy
\to \int f(0) \times \frac { dy}{y^2 + 1} 
= \pi f(0)
$$
so $$
\frac {\epsilon }{x^2 + \epsilon ^ 2} \to  \pi\delta
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you take a look at the discussion on some of the other answers and weight in?

Comment: The other answers are about th pointwise limit of the sequence; mine is about the limit in terms of distribution. There is no contradiction, other answers seem correct as well.

Comment: Well I was more so wondering about whether or not this is the correct answer if the limit must be a function on the reals? I would still think that $x=0$ should be undefined

Comment: the limit in terms of distribution is not a function on the reals.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the notion of a limit of functions with that of a numerical limit. As long as you're willing to work with the extended real numbers, the function
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} \infty & \text{if}~x = 0\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
is a perfectly valid limit function; in fact, a pretty well-known one, the Dirac delta.

If you don't want extended reals, you'll still have a limit function defined everywhere except at zero.

Comment: To be the Dirac delta, it should be valued 1 at $x=0$

Comment: It should *integrate* to $1$ (in distribution sense), but it is usually taken to be valued $+\infty$ at $0$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I've also considered this, but as you said I don't think this can really be called a function on the reals. So I think I'll just go with the function undefined in $x=0$.

Comment: @AdLibitum no. consider my answer.

Comment: @neuguy: ok, sorry, I was thinking to the Dirac *measure*, not function ....